# QSpacerItem expand horizontally

Tags: c++, qt

I would like my spacer item to push everything to the left. Currently this is what I do

```
QSpacerItem* spc = new QSpacerItem(5000000, 0, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

I wanted to know what was the correct way. I am currently setting the width to a very large number.

Comment: Wouldn't theLayout->addStretch() be the easy way to get the behavior you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0,0` with expanding horizontal size policy should work.

```
QSpacerItem* spc = new QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

You can also see the `QBoxLayout` [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/529b30b96435491fc6994515862f44d24efc754f%3asrc/gui/kernel/qboxlayout.cpp#L941) to see how Qt does it.